# Is there a scenario where adding a const qualifier to a local variable could introduce a runtime error?

Tags: c++, refactoring, const-correctness

Here's an (admittedly brain-dead) refactoring algorithm I've performed on several occasions:

1. Start with a `.cpp` file that compiles cleanly and (AFAICT) works correctly.
2. Read through the file, and wherever there is a local/stack-variable declared without the `const` keyword, prepend the `const` keyword to its declaration.
3. Compile the `.cpp` file again
4. If any fresh compile-time errors are reported, examine the relevant lines of code to determine why -- if it turns out the local-variable legitimately does need to be non-`const`, remove the `const` keyword from it; otherwise fix whatever underlying issue the `const` keyword's addition has revealed.
5. Goto (3) until the `.cpp` file again compiles cleanly

Setting aside for the moment whether or not it's a good idea to "const *all* the local variables", is there any risk of this practice introducing a run-time/logic error into the program that wouldn't be caught at compile-time?  AFAICT this seems "safe" in that it won't introduce regressions, only compile-time errors which I can then fix right away; but C++ is a many-splendored thing so perhaps there is some risk I haven't thought of.

Comment: I can't see any problems with this approach, but I honestly don't see any benefits to it either.  What do you gain from it?

Comment: @MarkRansom I find code with `const`-tagged local variables easier and quicker to review for correctness.  i.e. if I see `const int foo = 5;`, I can more-or-less assume that wherever I see `foo` later on, its value will be `5`.  OTOH if I see `int foo = 5;`, now when I see `foo` later on, I'll need to carefully eyeball the code between those two locations to see if/how `foo`'s value might have changed along the way.  Also, when all the variables that *can be* const *are* const, any remaining non-`const` variables stick out like a sore thumb, which helps me understand how they are used.

Comment: If the variable used to be moved, the move will be replaced with a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to accept a contrived example, you could enter the world of undefined behavior.

```cpp
void increment(int & num)
{
    ++num;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 99;
    increment(const_cast<int&>(n));
    cout << n;
}
```

The above compiles and outputs 100. The below compiles and is allowed to do whatever it wants (but happened to output 99 for me). [Modifying a const object through a non-const access path results in undefined behavior.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)

```cpp
void increment(int & num)
{
    ++num;
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 99;
    increment(const_cast<int&>(n));
    cout << n;
}
```

Yes, this is contrived because why would someone do a `const_cast` on a non-`const` object? On the other hand, this is a simple example. Maybe in more complex code this might actually come up. *Shrug* I won't claim that this is a big risk, but it does fall under "any risk", as stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding const to a variable can cause a different overload to be called:

https://godbolt.org/z/aE3jzPjP3

```
#include <stdexcept>

void func(int &) {
}

void func(const int &) {
    throw std::runtime_error("");
}

int main() {
    int var = 0;
    func(var);
}
```

Changing `var` to const will cause the program to call a different function and thereby throw an exception.

It can easily trigger completely different behaviour:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Map {
public:
    std::map<int, int> data;
    int func() {
       return data[5];
    }
    int func() const {
       const auto iter = data.find(5);
       return iter == data.end() ? -1 : iter->second;
    }
};

int main() {
    Map m; // try with const
    std::cout << m.func(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << m.data.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`const` has no runtime implications, that the compiler will not tell you at compile time and fail the build.